# How to remove entity and children

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persist

I have one problem to solve. I have two entities: `Action` and `Logging`:

```
@Entity
public class Action {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    ...other fields
    ...other fields


    @Column
    private Date start;

    @Column
    private Date end;


@Entity
public class Logging {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "action_id")
    private Action action;

    ..not important fields

    @Column
    private String domain;

    @Column
    private Date date;
```

Only Logging table has a column `action_id` as a `FOREIGN KEY`.

One action can have multiple Logging records.

The question is: how can I delete all Action entities that have a date before a certain date and have a certain domain (which lies in a Logging table)?
For example

```
deleteActionByDateAndDomain(LocalDateTime date, String domain)
```

Logging entity is the owner, right? So, Should I delete Action entity and then all related Logging entities by for example CASCADING? Or conversely - firstly remove all Logging entities which fulfill my conditions (`date before dateX and domain == myDomain` passed as parameters)?

How would you implement it?
I could, for example, delete Action entity and all related Logging entities but there is no field domain in Action entity (only in Logging).

If possible, I should use CrudRepository interface.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the cascade type to cascade the delete operation by setting the attribute `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` but this may cause you some headaches if not used correctly:

- If you delete some record by mistake, potentially a lot of data can be deleted in cascade
- The application can become slow because of many queries executed by Hibernate ([link](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/))

So, if you don't want these issues, you can manage the deletions manually. When you delete some record you will know what else needs to be deleted as a consequence. The advantage is that you have more control and you can optimize the process by creating bulk deletions if needed.

Comment: So, you say that I should manually delete all Logging records? FOr example I have one Action record and 5 Logging records that point to this Action record (by foreign key). So you say that I should firstly remove all Logging records and then manually check if there is orphan Action record that has no Logging records? The question is how to remove Action record with all related Logging records. We want to delete Action record by date and domain BUT domain lies in Logging entity. So in my opinion we have to start from Logging entity and finally delete Action entity if no Logging record exists.

Comment: I say, when you need to delete an `Action`, you first invalidate/delete all records that shouldn't exist without the `Action`, in your case all `Logging` associated to it, and then delete the `Action` itself, to leave the database in a consistent state.

Comment: Ok, all manually, no Cascading etc. But how can I check if there is an Action record with no Logging records related to it (Action) because I have already removed all related Logging entries? Action record without any related Logging entries shouldn't exist.

Comment: Right. You have the relation Logging -> Action. When you delete a particular Logging, take the associated Action, if it has no Loggings, delete it. It is the same idea.

Comment: I have thought that in this situation orphanRemoval = true could be helpful. For example when no Logging entries exist then Hibernate automatically removes the Action entry without any entries in Logging.

Comment: Yes, I believe you can use it, but it applies on OneToOne  and OneToMany annotations, so you should define the relation from the Action entity. But also, from the jpa documentation this approach is rather aggressive. I would do it manually.